# Prestshop 1.6 module custom search view

Tags: php, module, prestashop-1.6

Hi everyone I'm writing an advanced search module for Prestashop 1.6 which looks for an association between products and some other features loaded in a custom table.

I've written a `ModuleFrontController` that after a form submit has to return the results page, but the view doesn't have the base layout.

Inside the `initContent()` method I call this function as written in the [Official documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Displaying+content+on+the+front+office)

```
$this->setTemplate('advanced-search.tpl');
```

But it shows only the products list and nothing else, no header, no footer, no sidebars...

This is my code:

```
class MyModuleSearchModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

    protected static $config_post_submit_values = ['action'];

    public function initContent()
    {

        parent::initContent();

        switch (Tools::getValue($this->getPostSubmitValue())) {
            // Filter action
            case 'filter_1':
            /*
             * DO STUFF TO RETRIEVE PRODUCTS
             */
            case 'filter_2':
            /*
             * DO STUFF TO RETRIEVE PRODUCTS
             */
            default:
                $products = [];
        }

        $this->smarty->assign(['products' => $products]);

        $this->setTemplate('advanced-search.tpl');
    }

    /**
     * Get the action submited from the configuration page
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getPostSubmitValue()
    {
        foreach (self::$config_post_submit_values as $value) {
            if (Tools::isSubmit($value)) {
                return $value;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you cannot access `smarty`, because this object is inside the `context` object.

So

```
$this->smarty->assign(['products' => $products]);
```

should be

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(['products' => $products]);
```

**Side note**

Turn on error logging, go to `/config/defines.inc.php` and change the line

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
```

to

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

Do not turn on `_PS_MODE_DEV` in production/live environment.